# Transforming data by collapsing rows in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I am having a hard time with a dataset that currently have rows showing like the first table, and i would like to change it to look like the bottom table (see picture).

Is this possible in SQL?

Example data::

[image: Example data]

In the case where a customer has not bought a specific product, it should just return null. tablename=dbo.sales

Does anyone know how to transform this?
I hope i have provided enough information to put me in the right direction.
Best, Kirstine

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example, but I think you should look after questions for 'pivot Table'

Comment: What happened to `customer2`/`product1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try combination of LISTAGG and REGEXP_SUBSTR

```
WITH TAB AS(
  SELECT customer,
         LISTAGG (product, ',')
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY customer) str
  FROM table
  GROUP BY customer
) 
select customer,
      regexp_substr(str, '[^,]*,', 1, 1) as product1
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,2) as product2
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,3) as product3
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,4) as product4
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,5) as product5
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,6) as product6
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,7) as product7
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,8) as product8
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,9) as product9
     ,regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+',1,10) as product10
from   TAB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want two products in separate columns, you can use aggregation:

```
select customer,
       min(product) as product1,
       nullif(max(product), min(product)) as product2
from t
group by customer;
```